# What happened to the GitHub "Content Attachments API"?

Tags: github, github-api

This GitHub blog https://github.blog/2018-12-10-introducing-content-attachments-api/

announces (includes the link) https://developer.github.com/apps/using-content-attachments/

This link is a 404 and searching your docs for "Content Attachments API" does not produce useful results.

There are several other links:

1. https://github.blog/changelog/2018-12-10-content-attachments-api-public-beta/
2. https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-12-10-content-attachments-api/
3. https://developer.github.com/changes/5/

but they seem to include nothing current.

Does anyone know what happened?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub support answered my query as follows:

Q: What happened?

> A: The feature was discontinued while still in Preview(beta) and those testing/using the beta feature as I understand were reached directly via emails.

Q: Are there equivalent options?

> A: No, there is no equivalent options.